# asp.net visual studio "forms" does not exist in namespace "system.windows"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reference, webforms

So, I know this has been asked here before. However, I have tried all the remedies suggested from prior versions of this question and researched MSDN as well, so I am hoping for some additional insight.

In a web forms application in Visual Studio 2015, I have a reference to a an object (WebBrowser) that is defined within System.Windows.Forms, and have a "using System.Windows.Forms" directive. However, Intellisense gives the error that "Forms" does not exist within System.Windows. But I have added a reference to the proper version of system.windows.forms dll, and it indeed shows in the references folder. I have checked the version on the dll and the application, and both are .net v4.5.2. Also, System.Windows.Forms shows in the object browser (and the WebBrowser class is in there as well).

I can build the application without error for some reason despite the missing reference, but get a "compilation error" when I try to run it in the browser.

I cannot think of any further info that might help. Thank you greatly for any further insight.

JimK

Comment: Why do you think you need to use Web browser control in an ASP.NET app?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "In a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2015" ?

Comment: This is a website application, and my task is to get code from an existing site imported into and working in an application. So, the code is pre-existing. The reason for the port is so that improvements can be made utilizing the debugging tools, which aren't available currently because it's just a non-build website. I successfully ported over another website and resolved dozens of reference errors. Just hit a wall with this one.